# Parsing Java comments with Antlr4

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I'm looking for a way to extend the [antlr4 java grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4), to be able to **parse** Java comments. This comments may contain data relative to the code where comment is placed.

Note: I'm aware that it's possible to instruct lexer to send comments to separate (HIDDEN) channel. This is not what I'm looking for as parsing comments this way would require a lot of extra code.

Since Java comments can appear almost anywhere in source code, is there a way to make a parser rule for Java comment that would not need to be placed all over the parser rules, in order account for all possible situations?

If this is not possible, what would then be the most straightforward rules to parse block and line comments before class/field/method definitions and line comments at the end of normal code lines?

Comment: What is your goal here? How can you "parse comments" if comments have no definite structure and are almost completely free-form? Are you trying to handle doc-block sections? If so, there are already tools for that...

Comment: Comments contain certain descriptions that I can parse by hand in code (think Javadoc, but it can be in any comment anywhere). I don't expect Antlr to parse it. However descriptions are tied to code where comments are placed, so when I parse a comment on a HIDDEN channel, I also need to look into AST before or after the comment (depending on block/line comment). Does this make sense? Thanks for helping.

Comment: (1) I'd try to see if there's some way to dynamically change which channel(s) the parser is looking at from within parser rules, which might depend on the target language. (2) I think it may be worth posting a new question with a sample of the kind of source-code you want to parse.